# HTML5 video in WebView on Samsung S4 (Android 4.4.2) issue

Tags: android, html, video, cordova

I have a weird issue playing videos embedded in video tags in my Phonegap 3.3 app on Samsung S4 + Android 4.4.2.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<video id='myvideo' autoplay=1 preload='auto'></video>
```

Videos are started via Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$('#myvideo').attr('src', 'http://...jpg');
$('#myvideo').attr('poster', 'http://...mp4');

$('#myvideo')[0].play();
```

Video does not start as expected.

The problem only turns out after upgrading from Android 4.2 to Android 4.4.2. The issue is not present on other smartphones running Android 4.4.2 (eg. Nexus 4, 5).

Comment: I read somewhere that autoplay attribute doesn't work for mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

add this setting to your webview settings

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

here is my js code to play video automatically and loop on it ( you can remove this part if you only want to play it once

```
// here is my code to find my video tag
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

// if there is a video tag found ( this js is in a separate js files ) we play the video
if (typeof myVideo !== "undefined")
{
    // setInterval allow me to monitor every 40 millisecond if the video is ending or not, if true we loop the video and play it again
    setInterval(function() {


        if ( myVideo.readyState != 0)
        {
            if (myVideo.paused) {
                myVideo.currentTime = 0;
                myVideo.play();
            }
        }            
    }, 40)
}
```

Comment: which android version do you run ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your .mp4 and .jpg are backwards.